# Replacing /e modifier with preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

In this snippet I get the famous error `preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback` in PHP 5.5.

```
    if (stripos($message, '[' . $tag . ']') !== false)
        $message = preg_replace('~\[' . $tag . ']((?>[^[]|\[(?!/?' . $tag . '])|(?R))+?)\[/' . $tag . ']~ie',
            "'[" . $tag . "]' . str_ireplace('[smg', '&#91;smg', '$1') . '[/" . $tag . "]'", $message);
```

I was told I need to do this:

- Add _callback in the function call,
- remove the 'e' modifier,
- and replace the replacement string with:

  ```
  function ($match) use ($tag) { return '[' . $tag . ']' . str_ireplace('[smg', '&#91;smg', $match[1]) . '[/' . $tag . ']'; }
  ```

Can you help me with this? I really don't know how to do that...

Comment: adding an example string and what you hope to obtain will be very helpfull, if want that someone make more than a simple translation and improve your code.

Comment: If I understand well the goal of this is to replace all `[` before `smg` inside all nested levels inside `[$tag]` tags with `&#91;`?

Comment: Will tell you as soon as I discover that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$pattern = '~(\[' . $tag . '])((?>[^[]++|\[(?!/?+' . $tag . '])|(?R))*+)(\[/'
         . $tag . '])~i';
$message = preg_replace_callback($pattern,
                                 function ($m) {
                                     return $m[1]
                                          . str_ireplace('[smg', '&#91;smg', $m[2])
                                          . $m[3];
                                 }, $message);
```

Notice: an other way (more readable) to write the same pattern with verbose mode and heredoc syntax:

```
$pattern = <<<EOF
~
(\[  $tag ])
( (?> [^[]++ | \[(?!/?+ $tag ]) | (?R) )*+ )
(\[/ $tag ])
~ix
EOF;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! :) Why that $m ?

Comment: @MultiformeIngegno: `$m` is the match array: `$m[0] => global match`, `$m[1] => capture group 1`, ... It is defined when you put the name (you want) as param of the anonymous function.

Comment: Thanks! Will test your snippet tomorrow and let you know!! :)

Comment: Should I keep the if line?

Comment: @MultiformeIngegno: No, it is (and was) useless.